# Extracting icon using WinAPI in Qt app

Tags: qt, winapi, icons, exe

I'm trying to extract icon from exe file using WinAPI, but it doesn't work.

**Here's the code:**

```
QIcon OSTools::AppsInterface::extractAppIcon(const QString &fileName) const {
    wchar_t *convertedName = new wchar_t[fileName.length() + 1];
    fileName.toWCharArray(convertedName);
    convertedName[fileName.length()] = '\0';
    HICON Icon = ExtractIcon(NULL, convertedName, 0);

    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromWinHICON(Icon);
    return QIcon(pixmap);
}
```

Code outputs:

```
QPixmap::fromWinHICON(), failed to GetIconInfo()
```

([`ExtractIcon` function on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

I think problem is that I send NULL instead of "*A handle to the instance of the application calling the function*". But, generally, I use Qt, and it's only one WinAPI function in my app.

What's wrong? What's correct way to extract icon using WinAPI? If you have another function proposal, please, give me an example. This is the first time I'm using WinAPI.

**UPDATE:** Yes, there is a better way. You may use [QFileIconProvider](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qfileiconprovider.html) class for doing such things.

Comment: I take it the `HICON` is not null? Try calling `GetIconInfo` directly to see what the error result is.

Comment: @Neil GetLastError() before calling GetIconInfo returns error 1402 "Invalid cursor handle", after - 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And solution was very simple. I just sent path to '.lnk' file instead of path to file. That's my inattention.

Comment: Ah, so your `Icon` was `NULL` all along?

Comment: @Neil hmmm... as good as i remember it pointed to the random memory point.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me, even with NULL. But obtaining the HINSTANCE is actually very simple. You have a problem elsewhere i guess. Does your target exe really have an embedded icon?

```
#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
#include <qt_windows.h>
#endif

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
  QString fileName("D:\\_dev\\eclipse\\eclipse.exe");
  wchar_t *convertedName = new wchar_t[fileName.length() + 1];
  fileName.toWCharArray(convertedName);
  convertedName[fileName.length()] = '\0';
  HINSTANCE hInstance = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);
  HICON Icon = ::ExtractIcon(hInstance, convertedName, 0);
  ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromWinHICON(Icon));
#endif
}
```

[image]

Comment: As an update to this answer, in Qt 5 `QPixmap::fromWinHICON` was removed. Please use `QtWin::fromHICON` instead (located under `<QtWinExtras/qwinfunctions.h>`).

Answer (score 2):

I used [QFileIconProvider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileiconprovider.html), and it worked perfectly. Try this :

```
QPushButton b;
b.show();

QIcon icon;
QFileIconProvider fileiconpr;
icon = fileIconProvider.icon(QFileInfo("/*file name*/"));

b.setIcon(icon);

// And you can also save it where you want : 
QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap( QSize(/*desired size*/)  );
pixmap.save("/Desktop/notepad-icon.png");
```

[Source](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/9890-Retrieving-a-file-s-icon).  Have a nice day.